# JSP Template tutorial. How do I use a jar file

Tags: java, templates, jsp, jar

I am trying to follow the tutorial for JSP Templates at:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/jsp_templates/

I am struggling to understand the `<%@ taglib uri='/WEB-INF/tlds/template.tld' prefix='template' %>` tag.

What is the `template.tld` file, where does this come from?

I have tried to download the Resourses file of source code but this just contains a `src.jar` file. How do I use this? I can't even open the file!?! How do I see the source code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the `jstl.jar`.  You need `standard.jar` and `jstl.jar` in your WEB-INF/lib for JSTL.

You can get what you need here:

http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/

Download the standard tag library and all its JARs; put them in your WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: Thanks - I'm new to Java so still getting to grips with some concepts.

Comment: We were all new once - no worries.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: Hi, I've imported the jar files into my WEB-INF/lib directory and updated by Java Build Path etc. I'm still getting the error: Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/WEB-INF/tlds/template.tld"

Comment: That's because that URI is incorrect.  Open up c.tld in standard.jar - you'll see an XML tag named '<uri>'.  Make your URI match the one used by the .tld.  For example, c.tld wants the URI to be _http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core (without the leading underscore).

Answer (score 1):

A `uri`, a *uniform resource identifier* is not necessarily pointing to any existing resource. It is an *identifier*, compare with url which is a *uniform resource locator* which helps you *locate* something. In many XML contexts for instance, it simply declares a namespace.

Sometimes the uri does however point to a real resource that you can read to get more information.

In this case you are declaring a namespace *template* to use in your jsp code (such as `<template:dosomething/>`) - the uri matches a uri declaration for whatever is implementing your tag functionality and can be found inside a jar (`jstl.jar` or `standard.jar`, can't remember which).